# Transfer file in C delievers mangled data

Tags: c, sockets, file-io

I'm a newbie in C programming. I am writing a function where the client copies a file from the server. However, when I open my newly created file it contains a lot of additional characters. How can I prevent it from copying useless data?

Relevant sections of the server follow

```
            if (file = fopen(buf, "r")){                
            //send the file     
//              while(fgets(buffer, 1024, file) != NULL){
//                  res = write(new_fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
//              }

            while(!feof(file)){
                fscanf(file,"%s",buffer);
                write(new_fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            }               
            fclose(file);               
        }
```

Relevant sections of the client follow

```
        fp = fopen ("testfile", "w");

        while(read(sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != -1){
            fputs(buffer, fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: First don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it doesn't work as you expect it to. The reason is that the EOF flag is not set until *after* a failed read operation, so you will call `fscanf` once when the file has already reached the end. Instead to `while (fscanf(...) == 1)`.

Secondly, depending on how you declare `buffer`, don't use `&buffer` or `sizeof(buffer)`. Neither in the sender or the receiver. If `buffer` is a pointer then `&buffer` will return a pointer to that pointer, and `sizeof(buffer)` will return the size of the pointer and not what it points to. Besides, if `buffer` is an array then it might not be completely filled by the input, so why send data you don't need? Only send `strlen(buffer) + 1` bytes (the `+1` is for the string terminator).

Oh and a third thing, don't use `fscanf` to read a line, use `fgets` instead. Or even better, to be more effective, use `fread` to fill the complete buffer and send it all in less calls.

Answer (score 2):

`read`() does not null terminate it's buffer. `fputs` requires a null terminated buffer.

```
    while(read(sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != -1){
        fputs(buffer, fp);
```

You can add the terminator with something like this:

```
    int n = 0;
    char buffer[SOME_CONSTANT];
    while((n = read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer - 1))) != -1){
        buffer[n] = 0;
        fputs(buffer, fp);
    }
```

Note also the declaration and use of `buffer` vs `&buffer` in the call to read.

Finally, see all of Joachim Pileborg's suggestions!